# Mysql - Update multiple records with different values on every record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Table1 have 5 records or more with different 'products' and different 'price' and 'discount' and 'NetPrice' for every product, my code below updates all the records at once but with one value which is the calculation value of the last record in the table, and not the calculation value for every record, how to get all records updated at once with (`NetPrice = Price - Discount`) for every record ?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","sales");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $calculation = ($row['Price'] - $row['Discount']); 
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table1 SET NetPrice=$calculation");  
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It can be easily done in a single SQL `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query updates all records each time.  You should perform the calculation right in the SQL query, no need for a While loop.

Here's an example:

```
UPDATE table1 SET NetPrice = Price - Discount
```

This will calculate the net price for each item in the table, saving the result in the NetPrice field for each item.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I removed the Loop and it worked fine .